# Why Can't rotate cloud group

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to rotate my cloud group like in the tutorial I'm following but I can't figure out how to select just the cloud group. I go into the other layer like he does, hit A to select all but I'm lot from there. Here is the tutorial and I'm at http://youtu.be/TJ_OcBh7F5I 33 minutes in

[image: Tutorial Image 1]

[image: Tutorial image 2, rotating the group to rotate the particles]

[image: My second layer and group (clouds]

[image: My first layer w/particles, can't figure out how to rotate particles through group]

Comment: Welcome Zach, it would be better if you add the screenshots and explain more what you doing ,( link to a video is not a good thing)

Comment: so hiting A does nothing in the second layer ?